# How to loop through filtered range and delete cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet that pulls names from an attendance roster. I have the range of cells being filtered so that the user can choose names under certain managers.

There is a series of columns that I have where someone can scan the badge of an employee and information associated with the employee will populate.

The ultimate goal is to have it so that when someone is scanned into the sheet, their name will be removed from the attendance roster so that it is easy to see who has been scanned and who hasn't. My code works if the sheet isn't filtered but having the names of every employee under every manager isn't helpful so I want to be able to have the use filter to see only they people they want to see while still being able to remove the names from the roster. Can anyone help me out?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("B7:B100000")
 If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
   Call LoopMatch
 End If     
End Sub

Sub LoopMatch()
Dim Scanned, NotScanned As Range
Dim i, j As Range
  Set Scanned = Worksheets("Main").Range("C7:C100000")
  Set NotScanned = Worksheets("Main").Range("J7:J100000")

  For Each i In Scanned.Cells
    For Each j In NotScanned.Cells
      If i.Value = j.Value Then
        Range("J" & j.Row & ":L" & j.Row).Delete
        Exit Sub
      Else
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. I've changed your Range declarations to only look at the used range instead of a large one (should speed up your code)
Instead of looping through all cells in the range, Loop through using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` this will loop through only the filtered range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    With Me
        Set KeyCells = .Range(.Cells(7, 2), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))
    End With
     If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       Call LoopMatch
     End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub LoopMatch()
    Dim Scanned, NotScanned As Range
    Dim i, j As Range

    With Worksheets("Main")
        Set Scanned = .Range(.Cells(7, 3), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row, 3))
        Set NotScanned = .Range(.Cells(7, 10), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row, 10))
    End With
    For Each i In Scanned.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      For Each j In NotScanned.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If i.value = j.value Then
          Range("J" & j.Row & ":L" & j.Row).Delete
          Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
      Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```